# How to make ray traces visible? Can I use blender for experiments with reflectors?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I need to make something like that:

[image: ray tracing program]

Comment: Not cycles, at least without modifying the source code

Comment: Just a wild guess. Instead of using "light". Couldn't this be simulated with particles instead?

Comment: @xuv, it's crutches.